# how to resize plot area in R mschart

Tags: r, mschart

I'm using R package `mschart` to populate MS chart into PPT. I have added add multiple charts into one slide using the function `ph_with_chart_at` to define the location of ppt. However, the plot area is too small.

How can I resize the plot?

**Example**:

here is the sample code, when you open the ppt, I want to enlarge the size the plot area or control the space between axis y 40%, 50%,60%...

```
library(officer)
library(mschart)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(Name=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                   wave_id=c("2017Q1","2017Q2","2017Q3","2017Q4","2017Q1","2017Q2","2017Q3","2017Q4"),
pct=c(0.68,0.71,0.70,0.72,0.57,0.57,0.57,0.58))

data1 <- data%>%
  ms_linechart(x="wave_id",y="pct",group="Name")%>%
  chart_labels(title=NULL,xlab="",ylab="")%>%
  chart_ax_y(limit_min = 0.4,limit=0.8,
             num_fmt='0%%',major_tick_mark="none",minor_tick_mark="none")

data1_theme<- mschart_theme(
  legend_text = fp_text(font.size=8),
  axis_text = fp_text(font.size=8),
  legend_position = "r",
  grid_major_line=fp_border(width=))

pptsdata1 <- set_theme(data1,data1_theme)


doc <- read_pptx()

doc <-doc%>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")%>%
  ph_with_chart_at(chart=pptsdata1,left=1,top=2,height=1.55,width=8)

print(doc, target = "my_plot.pptx")
```

If you look at the outputted graph, you can see that the plot only takes up a small amount of the plot area, with a lot of white space left around the plot:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a basic example of your problem? Check out here on how to make a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, have you tried the `width` and `height` arguments within the `ph_with_chart_at` function?

Comment: The width and height arguments within the ph_with_chart_at is used to control the position of chart on ppt. I'm OK with that.  My issue is when I create line chart, the plot area is very small, and I need to go to ppt manually resize the plot area to fit the report.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mschart/mschart.pdf), `left` and `top` should control the position on the existing slide. I willl happy to assist if you can provide an example code: at the moment I can only guess you problem. Please edit the question to include this example.

Answer (score 2):

**Changing the plot size**

You can use the `width` and `height` arguments within the `ph_with_chart_at` function to specify the output width and height respectively, while the `left` and `top` arguments control the position in the slide. For example `ph_with_chart_at(chart=pptsdata1, left=2, top=1, height=3, width=8)`

**Editing Size of Plot Margins (i.e. whitespace around plot)**

You problem arises as you are trying to hide the titles of the axes. As there appears no way to suppres them completely, what we:

1. Replace the labels with a single space i.e. `""`
2. Change the font size of the axis title to `axis_title = fp_text(font.size=1)`

Updating your example:

```
library(officer)
library(mschart)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(Name=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                   wave_id=c("2017Q1","2017Q2","2017Q3","2017Q4","2017Q1","2017Q2","2017Q3","2017Q4"),
pct=c(0.68,0.71,0.70,0.72,0.57,0.57,0.57,0.58))

data1 <- data%>%
  ms_linechart(x="wave_id",y="pct",group="Name")%>%
  chart_labels(title=NULL,xlab=" ",ylab=" ")%>%
  chart_ax_y(limit_min = 0.4,limit=0.8,
             num_fmt='0%%',major_tick_mark="none",minor_tick_mark="none")

data1_theme<- mschart_theme(
  axis_title = fp_text(font.size=1),
  legend_position = "r",
  grid_major_line=fp_border(width=))

pptsdata1 <- set_theme(data1, data1_theme)

doc <- read_pptx()

doc <-doc%>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")%>%
  ph_with_chart_at(chart=pptsdata1, left=1,  top=1,  height=3,  width=8)

print(doc, target = "my_plot.pptx")
```

[image]

Comment: This is the chart area, I want to resize the plot area (which doesn't include legend, axis title)

Comment: Okay, I think we have got there now! I hope you my feedback has helped you see how to make the question clearer in future cases: it is important to clearly state the exact problem so that others know how to help  :) if you find the solution useful, can you mark it as accepted and upvote it please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can you explian why legend_text=fp_text(font.size=0)?

Comment: I'll tell you if you mark the answer as accepted and upvote it ;) just kidding, I think that was left by accident. Just removed it from the answer.